# operator to access other classes's objects

Tags: c#

I need help with this code. If you run the code you'll get in the last 7 lines (which is for...loop for *Order* object) Exercise.OrderItem.The problem is that I would like to access the *OrderItem* objects with for...loop but all I get are the last 7 lines representing *OrderItem* objects.How can I access them in for...loop so that I get the same as in foreach...loop? I think it has something to do with the indexer.Thank You.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Collections;

    namespace Exercise
    {
        interface IPricing
        {
            //read/write property
            double Price
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            double Discount
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
        public class Order:IPricing
        {
            private string name;
            private double price;
            private static int OrderNo;
            //private ArrayList m_items = new ArrayList();
            private ArrayList m_items;


            //static constructor
            static Order()
            {
                OrderNo = 0;
            }

            //default constructor
            public Order()
            {
                name = null;
                price = 0;
                OrderNo++;
                m_items = new ArrayList();
            }
            //constructor with parameters
            public Order(string name, double price)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.price = price;
                OrderNo++;
                this.m_items = new ArrayList();
            }
            //copy constructor
            public Order(Order order)
            {
                this.name = order.name;
                this.price = order.price;
                this.m_items = order.m_items;
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get { return name; }
                set { name = value; }
            }

            public IEnumerable Items
            {
                get { return m_items; }
                private set { }
            }

            public void AddItem(OrderItem orderItem)
            {
                orderItem.Order = name;
                m_items.Add(orderItem);
            }

            public static Order operator +(Order o1, Order o2)
            {
                Order o3 = new Order(o1.name+", "+o2.name,o1.price+o2.price);
                o3.m_items.AddRange(o1.m_items);
                o3.m_items.AddRange(o2.m_items);
                return o3;
            }

            //indexer 
            public object this[int index]
            {
                get 
                {
                    m_items[index] = this.m_items[index];
                    return m_items[index];
                }
                set { m_items[index] = value; }
            }

            public double ItemCount
            {
                get { return m_items.Count; }
                private set{}
            }


            public virtual void Print()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*********************Order No. {0}***********************", OrderNo);
                Console.WriteLine("Details");
                Console.WriteLine("Name:              {0}", name);
                Console.WriteLine("Price:             {0}", price);
            }

            public double Price
            {
                get { return price - Discount; }
                set { price = value; }
            }

            public virtual double Discount
            {
                get { return 0; }
                set { ;}
            }

            public void PrintItems()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Items in this order: ");
                Console.WriteLine();
                foreach(OrderItem itm in this.m_items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Item name: {0,4};\tPart of order: {1}", itm.Name, itm.Order);
                }
            }


}

        public class OrderItem
        {
            private string m_name; //name of the item in order
            private string m_order; //name of the order whose parts are items with names m_name
            //default constructor
            public OrderItem()
            {
                m_order = null;
            }
            //parameter constructor
            public OrderItem(string name)
            {
                this.m_name = name;
                this.m_order = null;
            }
            //copy constructor
            public OrderItem(OrderItem orderItem)
            {
                this.m_name = orderItem.m_name;
                this.m_order = orderItem.m_order;
            }

            //Name read/write property
            public string Name
            {
                get { return m_name; }
                set { m_name = value; }
            }

            //Order read/write property
            public string Order
            {
                get { return m_order; }
                set { m_order = value; }
            }
        }

        public class MainProgram
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string order1 = "Desktop PC";
                Order desktopPC = new Order(order1,25000);
                desktopPC.AddItem(new OrderItem("pc mouse"));
                desktopPC.AddItem(new OrderItem("keyboard"));
                desktopPC.AddItem(new OrderItem("monitor"));
                desktopPC.AddItem(new OrderItem("pc"));

                desktopPC.Print();
                desktopPC.PrintItems();

                Console.WriteLine();


                string order2 = "Notebook";
                Order notebook = new Order(order2, 54000);
                notebook.AddItem(new OrderItem("mouse"));
                notebook.AddItem(new OrderItem("bag"));
                notebook.AddItem(new OrderItem("notebook"));


                notebook.Print();
                notebook.PrintItems();


                Console.WriteLine();
                Order total = desktopPC + notebook;
                total.Print();
                total.PrintItems();
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Getting the items via for loop");
                for (int k = 0; k < total.ItemCount; k++)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(total[k]);
                }

                    Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is MUCH more code than is really needed to explain your problem. Consider cutting out the irrelevant bits, or posting a short equivalent snippet instead.

Comment: Please describe the problem better, I cannot really see what is the question... This for cycle should return you the 7 items of the order, which I understood it does... What is the expected output and what is the actual output?

Comment: @anaximander: Sorry,I thought it would help to see the whole thing

Comment: @TomasPastircak: I want to get the actual items (pc mouse, keyboard,monitor,..) in the last instead of what I get now.

Comment: @Mikee.Cara No worries. You say in your question you're asking about the last 7 lines; in that case, I'd suggest only posting those 7 lines, plus whichever bits are needed to understand what's happening in those 7 lines. All the rest of your program logic is unrelated to your question, so we don't need to see it.

Comment: The instance total or Order doesn't have any OrderItems in it as far as I can see.

Comment: @Mikee.Cara Then maybe use `Console.WriteLine(total[k].Name);` or consider overriding ToString() method on the OrderItem? Still not sure what results are you getting now...

Comment: Have you tried just casting `total[k]` as an `OrderItem`? That is `OrderItem item = (OrderItem)total[k]`? (Though really it would be best to do this in the indexer on Order but that line is the easiest way to test.

Comment: @Chris: No, that doesn't work.

Comment: @Chris:Sorry, you were right. It didn't occurred to me that I can just cast it like that.Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned rather than casting on use you are best off changing your indexer to `public OrderItem this[int index]` and putting the cast in there. Or better yet rather than storing in an ArrayList use a `List<OrderItem>` or similar...

Comment: @Chris: OK, thanks a lot. I have been doing C# for only one or two months so I often forget that CASTING exists. Also I haven't done much with the indexers. I appreciate you helping me. Yeah, generic collection would be better.

Comment: @Mikee.Cara: I assumed that was the case which is why I thought I'd offer the extra advice. Glad its helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        for (int k = 0; k < total.ItemCount; k++)
        {
            var x = total[k] as OrderItem;
            if (x == null) continue;
            Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(x.Order);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Nevertheless because I am novice to C# I don't understand the first line in for cycle. Can you explain it?

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out. It is just simple casting as @Chris said in his first comment.

Comment: @Mikee.Cara: The first line is a sort of conditional casting. The `as` operator will attempt to cast the object to that type. If it succeeds you get that object appropriately cast, if the cast fails it returns null instead. In this case it isn't that necessary because you should know that `total[k]` is always of type `OrderItem` so the conditional is unnecessary. In the event you get something that isn't an OrderItem that is probably indicative that something has gone wrong elsewhere so an exception would probably be what you want here.